# Why is this simply mysql 'LIKE' query failing? (Error included)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
`vehicleid`,
`companyvehicleid`,
`stocknumber`,
`year`,
`make`,
`model`,
FROM `vehicle`
WHERE `stocknumber` LIKE '100' LIMIT 20
```

And the error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `vehicle` WHERE `stocknumber` LIKE '100' LIMIT 20' at line 8
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of your select clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
`model`,  // this comma is the problem
FROM ...
```

You have one `,` before the `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
`vehicleid`,
`companyvehicleid`,
`stocknumber`,
`year`,
`make`,
`model`
FROM `vehicle`
WHERE `stocknumber` LIKE '100' LIMIT 20
```

You had a comma after `model` this is what was causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after the last column in your SELECT statement. Try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the last comma (,) between 'model' and FROM